# Send message to another window upon Enter key press

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I want my test data goes to another window after <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press, like a click on the send  button.

I'm using this code:

```
    text1 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textMsg));
    text1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
              // Perform action on key press
             Toast.makeText(IMSendData.this, text1.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return true;
            }

            return false;
        }  
    });
```

Using this code after I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, its goes on send button, and after second <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press the test data goes to the window.

I want to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> button only once and then the text go to the window.

Comment: I want when i press enter key then written text go to the window(only one key press not two time , now its happening for two time to press enter key)

Comment: What do you mean by another window, provide your code to help you better

Comment: For example - During Instance messaging we chat with each other , here i want to we write some text in edit text box after complete the line when we press enter key at same time its goes to the chat main window...

Comment: Your code is correct, just after Toast.makeText add the code to open or show the desired window passing editText text value. It depends on the architecture of your windows and how you created them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 you go through this..



            sendData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
            sendData.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == 
                                      KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                // Perform action on key press
                adapter.add(new OneComment(false,  
                                    sendData.getText().toString()));
                sendData.setText("");
                return true;
            }
            return false;
           }
           });
```